Is it patronising and infantilising to always include the term "we" when working in hospitality?
I have to say I feel really uncomfortable at the approach of one of the bar staff in a village pub I visit. He will refer to customers, new or regular, male or female as "my love", "love" or "treacle" and virtually always includes himself by using "we" in questions like "how are we today?, "have we decided on a meal?", "do we fancy a desert?". Am I being oversensitive but personally I find it feels odd, patronising and infantilising? It is not that I think he should be calling everyone Sir or Madam but I just get this creepy feeling of being talked to like I am in someway deficient! I'm in my 50's and this is a male in his early 20's - so probably thinks I'm one foot in the grave!

Yes. If a staff member speaks of 'we' it usually refers to the management team, the establishment. So if they ask "how are we doing?" you could reply "Your service is a bit slow / very quick / your team is very good today"

In my experience, depending on the gender and age of the speaker/addressee, using endearments can feel patronising/creepy or simply be the speaker's natural way of being friendly to strangers.

Oh please, if the person is nice, what's the problem? No everybody speaks in the same way. In English, they say "love" all the time in shops and cafes. I've been there many times and it never fails. As for the we, onbe often hears/sees it. So what?
